# Moving blog info in nav bar mobile in WP-Forge

Tags: css, wordpress, zurb-foundation

I'm using the WP-Forge theme for Wordpress and I would like to move the blog title on mobile into the menu bar. I've done this loads of times in plain Foundation but am struggling like nobody's business to work out how to do it.

If anyone has any experience or advice on how to do this, I'd be very grateful. I'm using the default WP-Forge theme, which is running on Foundation 6.3.1.1.

I've uploaded an exact copy of the theme here http://ppgdev.com/ross/imagepress/

If you need anything else please do not hesitate to ask - something I can normally do in five minutes is driving me nuts. Already spent a full day at work on this :(

Thanks in advance,

Ross

Comment: Do you mean move `.site-title` from `#header` into `.title-bar`? You've tagged it as PHP (rather than JS, HTML or CSS) so are looking for a server-side solution?

Comment: You're right, I have labelled it incorrectly. I'll re-label it now. Thanks for spotting that!